# working with data types in haskell

Tags: haskell

So I have this code(Haskell) here which I am trying to figure out, I've searched everywhere for a solution and I couldn't find any.

```
data Expr = Var String | Const Int | Neg Expr | Expr `Plus` Expr | Expr `Times` Expr 
     deriving (Show,Eq)

transform::(Expr->Expr)->Expr->Expr
transform t (Neg e) = t (Neg(transform t e))
transform t (e1 `Plus` e2) = t ((transform t e1) `Plus` transform t e2)
transform t e = t e

sublocal :: (String->Expr)->Expr->Expr
sublocal t (Var s) = t s
sublocal t exp = exp

substitute :: (String->Expr)->Expr->Expr
substitute t exp = transform (sublocal t) exp

reduce :: Expr->Expr
reduce (Neg(Const x)) = Const(-x)
reduce ((Const x) `Plus` (Const y)) = Const(x+y)
reduce e = e

simplify ::(String ->Expr)->Expr->Expr
simplify t e = transform reduce (substitute t e)
```

I don't understand this here:

```
transform::(Expr->Expr)->Expr->Expr
transform t (Neg e) = t (Neg(transform t e))
transform t (e1 `Plus` e2) = t ((transform t e1) `Plus` transform t e2)
transform t e = t e
```

What valid inputs can this function receive in order for it to work ? Can you please show me some valid inputs for the function to work ?
I don't understand what values to pass to the function to match this definition: `(Expr->Expr)`

Comment: `(Expr -> Expr)` is just a function type, so at the simplest you could pass the function `id` which just returns it's argument, so `transform id` would be a "do nothing" operation.  You could have something like `incrConst (Const a) = Const (a + 1); incrConst other = other` so that `transform incrConst` would be a function `Expr -> Expr` that would increment all values wrapped in the `Const` constructor.

Comment: @bheklilr can you give me a full `transform` input that would work ? defining the `inscrConst` and doing `transform incrConst` gave me the following error: No instance for (Show (Expr -> Expr)) ( maybe you haven't  applied enough arguments to a function?)

Comment: You have to fully apply the function.  `transform` takes two arguments and is what is known as a higher order function, like `map` or `filter`.  Something like `transform incrConst (Const 1)` would return `Const 2`, although it wouldn't be very interesting.  However `transform incrConst (Plus (Const 1) (Const 2))` would return `Plus (Const 2) (Const 3)`

Comment: Don't take it personally. If you understand the individual pieces here (which I would expect anyone familiar with Haskell to be able to do easily), but don't understand how they fit together, then you should have written your question in a way that reflects and demonstrates that. You say that you "searched everywhere for a solution" but not what you did and did not manage to figure out about what the code does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`transform` takes two arguments.

- A function (any function) that accepts an `Expr` and returns an `Expr`.
- An `Expr` to apply this function to.

It looks like the idea is similar to `map`: take a function and apply it to every part of something. (Although, as written, it only deals with `Neg` and `Plus`.)

You could try the `id` function, which won't do anything:

```
> transform id (Neg (Const 5))
Neg (Const 5)
```

Or you could apply some more interesting function:

```
> transform reduce (Neg (Const 5))
Const (-5)
```

Comment: in this example: `transform id (Neg (Const 5))` the `t` from `transform` function takes the `id` parameter that I pass?

Comment: Yes.  The first argument goes to the first parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The type `Expr` defines an abstract syntax tree:  a datastructure describing the parsed form of a very simple expression language.

You can define functions that take an `Expr` as an argument, do some manipulation on it, and return another `Expr` as their result.  The function `reduce` in your code example is one of these -- if the root of the tree is something it can "reduce", it will do so, otherwise it will return its input unprocessed

The function `transform` takes a function like `reduce`, and returns another one.  Specifically, for the exact cases that `reduce` is able to reduce, `transform` applies the input function recursively, so that the subtrees of the `Neg` and `Plus` cases are "transformed" first, before the input function is applied to the `Neg` or `Plus` node itself.

The upshot is:  if you compose an `Expr` tree out of only `Plus` and `Neg` nodes, with only `Const` leaves, then applying `transform reduce` will "reduce" the entire tree, returning a `Const` value which contains the result of evaluating the expression described by the input tree.